# vb.net vs2008 empty executable

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, header, exe

Is it possible to compile a vb.net project into an empty exe file (only containing the header information like version number, company, product name etc) in VS2008?

Comment: You ask me - I am as confused as you... It is a request from one of our clients (a bank). They wish to have this file included in the installation set.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in this shoban. I did ask why - they told me that it was part of their "internal software identification", like that should explain anything....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  A managed .exe requires a Main() method.